# js function onclick needs to click one time to change the font

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

an event is working fine in js when clicked twice to change the font.I want same should work on single click as well.

**js code is below.**

```
function changered() {
iconsred.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('fas');
    event.style.color= "#ff0000";
 }) }
```

**HTML code is below.**

```
<a onclick="changered()" href="#">
   <div class="thumb-down">
     <i id="iconsred" class="far fa-thumbs-down fa-5x right"></i>
   </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the eventlistener after the first click, that's why you need the first click.

I'm not sure if it fits your needs since its a little different but you can change the color on the `changered` callback instead of adding an event listener. Something like:

```
function changered() {
  icon = document.getElementById('iconsred');
  icon.classList.toggle('fas');
  icon.style.color= "#ff0000";
}
```

Comment: yes why i didn't thought of doing it this way!! thank you @arieljoud you're a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you add the click event on the `<a>`?

`iconsred` does not have a click event, before you run `changered()` that is why you need to click it twice.

You could do it like this:

```
var iconsred = document.getElementById("iconsred")
iconsred.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('fas');
  event.target.style.color = "#ff0000";
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var iconsred = document.getElementById("iconsred")
iconsred.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('fas');
  event.target.style.color = "#ff0000";
})
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="thumb-down">
    <i id="iconsred" class="far fa-thumbs-down fa-5x right">test</i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: i thought a is the main tag so calling it on the anchor will solve my problem but nothing happen

Comment: it still doing the same thing working on double click after i  put event in <i> tag wher im calling the font

Answer (score 0):

It's because you create a new eventListener the first time it is clicked, and therefore it works the second time you make the click.

You can add it to the document, and only react on the specific element if you give it an id:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(e.target.id === "yourId") {
       event.target.style.color= "#ff0000";
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
After DOM loaded we are adding listener.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   iconsred.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('fas');
    event.style.color= "#ff0000";
   })
   });
```

```html
<a onclick="changered()" href="#">
   <div class="thumb-down">
     <i id="iconsred" class="far fa-thumbs-down fa-5x right">test</i>
   </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Actually in inspect i can see classlist toggle works. Do you want to change the color ?

Comment: im changing the font as you can see in html im calling class = "far fa-thumbs-down " and on click it'll change to the filled thumbs up which is also a font called from js "event.target.classList.toggle('fas')"

Comment: @ErdemOzdemir You have not defined `iconsred` anywhere

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen because not necessary :) Give it a try and try to select <i> tag and just write console  "iconsred". You will see it's select <i> tag

Comment: but it still hasn't solved the problem here @ErdemOzdemir

Comment: @ErdemOzdemir When i run it, i get 2 errors. `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined",` and `changered is not defined"`

Comment: but with my code it's changing the color and also not giving this undefined error i just want it to run on single click and it's still not working @ErdemOzdemir